# Is it Pythonic to nest generators within generators?

Tags: python, optimization, generator, list-comprehension

I need to build large trees of empty nested dictionaries and would like to know if the code below is Pythonic:

```
dictionary_name = dict((year, dict((month, dict((day, []) for day in days))
                       for month in months)) for year in years)
```

- If this is bad practice, what is the most Pythonic way of writing the above code?
- If this is not bad practice, where should I use line-breaks to keep this legible and "Pythonic". Also, is the speed advantage of generators still present when nesting them?

**Notes:** This question also applies to list comprehensions. Please let me know if you think I should break this question into multiple questions.

Comment: If it's more readable, it's "pythonic".

Comment: Yes, very so. What do you think would be a pythonic alternative?

Comment: Should I rename the question to "is it efficient to [...]"?

Comment: That depends on what you want to ask.

Comment: I'd say this code it goes against "sparse is better than dense". But maybe some better formatting would help.

Comment: I think it's both. I assumed Pythonic referred to "efficient" in both meanings of the term (speed and legible).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to create 1 dictionary with tuples of `(year,month,day)` as keys instead?

Comment: You should consider dict comprehensions if you are just going to make a dict out of these generators anyway http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: +1 for @mgilson comment. Anyway, about making that code more readable, I usually try to put the "fors" on different lines. I think in this way it becomes pretty clear which is inside which generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have above is a little too dense for my taste ... I actually generally avoid nesting expressions like that because I have a hard time remembering whether they get read from the inside out, or outside in, or via some sort of strange magic random method.  That said, I know there are others who write great python code who nest sometimes and I think it's Ok as long as you don't nest too deep.

Personally, I would probably create a `dict` which uses tuples to index it -- And I might consider using a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictionary_name = defaultdict(list)
dictionary_name[(year,month,day)].append(data)
#your way would be:  `dictionary_name[year][month][day].append(data)`
```

This is (IMHO) a much easier to understand piece of code than what you have above (i.e. more pythonic).

If you don't want a `defaultdict`, you could use `itertools.product` to build the dict:

```
dictionary_name = dict( ( k,[] ) for k in it.product(years,months,days) )
```

or

```
dictionary_name = { k:[] for k in it.product(years,months,days) }  #py2.7+
```

Comment: Note that you do not even need to use () for the index; within [] the comma separated items are automatically turned into a tuple

Comment: There's a real difference in usage though between the original nested data structure and this flattened dictionary. This loses structure that was present in the original.

Comment: @chepner -- Yes there is (no contention there) -- And that may make this a deal-breaker.  I'm just saying that choosing an appropriate structure for the data is part of being `pythonic`, but that relies on information we don't know.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala -- Yeah, the extra paren aren't necessary, but they don't hurt either.  I find that it helps to group the elements so that I immediately know where the value ends and the iteration starts.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using a `defaultdict`, I'd go with

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
dd = defaultdict( defaultdict )
for y, m, d in itertools.product( years, months, days ):
    dd[y][m][d] = []
```

Comment: Nice solution! Even though I'd still avoid nesting them.

Comment: I wish I could choose 2 answers! Yours is probably more in line with what I initially posted, but mgilson's is more practical for my exact purposes.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension complexity is more a matter of personal / dev. team style than a pure question of "being Pythonic". A good potential reference tool for situations like this is the [Google Python Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html).  Their [section on listcomps](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#List_Comprehensions) says:

> Okay to use for simple cases.

with a "decision" (i.e., how Google internally came down on the issue):

> Okay to use for simple cases. Each portion must fit on one line: mapping expression, for clause, filter expression. Multiple for clauses or filter expressions are not permitted. Use loops instead when things get more complicated.

Personally, I'll go for nested listcomps *as long as they're immediately understandable*, and otherwise decompose into multiple parts, functions, etc.

Other notes to your questions:

- Yes, you can do line breaks in listcomps, and it sometimes helps readability.
- For speed, the answer is "it depends", and is probably more of a separate question for Stack Overflow (and I'm quite confident you'll find some good starting points here). If nothing else: (1) Make sure this is a bottleneck, then (2) benchmark alternatives.

Ultimately, the style issue is a matter of "use your judgement" -- just be considerate of the other dev's who will later encounter your code.

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with the other posters that this expression is a bit dense, and it might be a good idea to break it up in another way, if you *are* going to write something that dense, a little indentation adjustment can go a long way into making it more readable:

```
dictionary_name = dict(
    (year, dict((month, dict((day, [])
                             for day in days))
                for month in months))
    for year in years)
```